How can I use #include in a GLSL file using C++
I want to use the #include directive in GLSL files so I don’t have to rewrite the same code for every GLSL shader I create. I tried to create my own small parser for this purpose, but I couldn’t find a good way to locate all #include statements in a GLSL file. I want to extract the paths of the included files, read them, and write their content into the actual shader (not the original GLSL file that uses the #include directive, but the content read into a std::string).
I attempted to find shader includes using the following code:
std::string include = "#include";
std::string shaderSource = ReadFile("shader.glsl");
std::uint32_t offset = 0, position = 0;
while ((position = shaderSource.find(include, offset)) != std::string::npos)
{
    offset += include.size();
    // parse the shader
}

However, I realize that this approach may not work in all scenarios, and I believe the solution should be more complex than what I've implemented.

I’m confused; it sounds like you are going backwards. An include lets you reuse stuff without having to maintain multiple copies in every file. This makes maintenance harder.

@Dúthomhas I'm not writing to the actual GLSL file so I guess it should be fine. Although I don't think I got your point.

@Newbieprogrammer what is your actual question? It looks like you already know how to read a file into a string and then search it.

Why can't you just use #include?

@Eljay OpenGL doesn't have a filesystem for it's shaders, so no I can't.

"I realize that this approach may not work in all scenarios" - You need to provide some examples of the files you read and the expected output.

I did not explain myself adequately.  Why can't you have source files that have #include directives that preprocess (using the C++ preprocessor, or whatever preprocessor you prefer (e.g., I've used m4 and Python before)) into the GLSL files as the output.

@Eljay Oh I get it, because I have a Shader class that takes a filesystem::path, not the source code.

@Ted Lyngmo It's pretty obvious if you think about it, if the length of the include path is greater than the length of "#include" then the while loop won't break. I hope I was clear.

@Newbieprogrammer I'm sorry, but that didn't make it clearer. Please update your question. Include an example file that you read into shaderSource - or just assign shaderSource with the content of such a file. See [mre].

No problem, I'll update my question.

You likely want offset = position + include.size(). Otherwise, you are going to find the same "#include" substring over and over. Let's say the substring is at position 100. You'll first find it when searching starting at offset 0; then again starting at offset 8; then again starting at offset 16; ... Whereas once you found it at position 100, you want to start searching from offset 108 (or 100 + the length of the whole directive).

@Igor Tandetnik Thanks! I'll try to implement it and see if it works or not. I appreciate your help.

Possibly relevant: How to Using the #include in glsl support ARB_shading_language_include

@Wyck is correct--you should just give the GLSL compiler the header file data, enable the include extension, and let it deal with actually substituting the contents in where needed.

For what it's worth, I think your title makes this a bit of an XY problem.  The title should probably be edited to just ask "How can I use #include in a glsl file?"  (The body of your question is mostly fine).  I think this title more closely matches the spirit of the question.  Especially since you said "the solution should be more complex than what I've implemented", which I interpret as, "the question should be more general than what I've asked".

@Wyck Got it, I edited my question.

I'd probably solve this using std::regex. Matching against something like #include\s*(?:\"|<)(.*.\w+)(?:\"|>) and you get your path/file from it basically for free.

Note: This version is done with C++ code, as you asked for in your comment on my other answer.
The idea is to search for text of the format #include "filename" and to recursively replace that text with the contents of the included file.
I've given some consideration to specifying additional include directories.  But I've also taken some shortcuts sacrificing robustness, particularly with the regular expression for matching "" or <>.
This version takes a string as its original input (not a file).  If you want to take input from a file, you can just process a string with a single #include directive that includes the desired file, or extend this implementation as you desire to read in the original file first.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>

// Read a file and return its contents as a string
std::string readFile(const std::string& fileName) {
    std::ifstream file(fileName);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file: " + fileName);
    }

    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << file.rdbuf();
    return buffer.str();
}

// Find the file in the current directory or in additional include directories
std::string findIncludeFile(const std::string& fileName, const std::vector<std::string>& includeDirs) {
    if (std::filesystem::exists(fileName)) {
        return fileName; // File found in the current directory
    }

    for (const auto& dir : includeDirs) {
        std::filesystem::path filePath = std::filesystem::path(dir) / fileName;
        if (std::filesystem::exists(filePath)) {
            return filePath.string(); // File found in one of the include directories
        }
    }

    throw std::runtime_error("File not found: " + fileName);
}

// Process `#include` directives
std::string processIncludes(const std::string& input, const std::vector<std::string>& includeDirs) {
    std::regex includeRegex(R"(#include\s*["<](.*?)[">])");
    std::smatch match;
    std::string output = input;
    std::string::const_iterator searchStart(output.cbegin());

    while (std::regex_search(searchStart, output.cend(), match, includeRegex)) {
        std::string includeFile = match[1].str();
        std::string fileContent;
        try {
            std::string filePath = findIncludeFile(includeFile, includeDirs);
            fileContent = readFile(filePath);
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e) {
            std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
            fileContent = "";
        }

        // Calculate the position in the full string for the replacement
        auto matchPos = match.position(0) + (searchStart - output.cbegin());
        output.replace(matchPos, match.length(0), fileContent);

        // Adjust the searchStart to continue at the inserted content (to allow nested includes)
        searchStart = output.cbegin() + matchPos;
    }

    return output;
}

int main() {
    // Example input string containing `#include` directives
    std::string input = R"(#include "example.glsl")";

    // List of additional include directories
    std::vector<std::string> includeDirs = { "./include", "./shaders" };

    try {
        std::string output = processIncludes(input, includeDirs);
        std::cout << "Processed Output:\n" << output << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

example.glsl
#include "common.glsl"

void main()
{
    FragColor = vertexColor;
}

common.glsl
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec4 vertexColor;

Output:
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec4 vertexColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vertexColor;
}


If the complexity of what you need to support for features is minimal, then you may be able to use your C/C++ compiler's preprocessor to accomplish this at build time.
example.glsl
#include "common.glsl"

void main()
{
    FragColor = vertexColor;
}

common.glsl
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec4 vertexColor;

Visual Studio Command Prompt
cl /P common.glsl /Fipreprocessed.glsl /EP

preprocessed.glsl (generated)
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec4 vertexColor;


void main()
{
    FragColor = vertexColor;
}

Equivalent command in gcc
gcc -E -P common.glsl -o preprocessed.glsl


Thanks, but I wanted to know if I could do it with c++ code not using the compiler to do that automatically.
